# UIButton in UITableViewCell makes table scrolling not smooth

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

Here I have UITableView that displays username list and it works just fine. **However, after I added UIButton into each cell for each username in order to follow/unfollow them, that makes the table scrolling very not smooth.** Here below is my relevant code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *identifier = @"reuseIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                  reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }


    //*** Display username ***
    NSString *userName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%@", [self.objects[indexPath.row] objectForKey:kPAWParseUsernameKey]];
    cell.textLabel.text = userName;
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];


    //*** Follow/Unfollow button -- This makes the table scrolling very not smooth ***
    UIButton *followButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:followButton];
    PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
    [query whereKey:kPAWParseUsernameKey equalTo:[self.objects[indexPath.row] objectForKey:kPAWParseUsernameKey]];
    NSArray *userArray = [query findObjects];
    PFUser *user = [userArray objectAtIndex:0];
    // set follow button image
    if ([[[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"followings"]containsObject:user.objectId]) {
        [followButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"following.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];    
    } else {
        [followButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unfollow.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    [followButton setFrame:CGRectMake(280.0f, 20.0f, 20.0f, 32.0f)];
    [followButton addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapFollowButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    return cell;

}
```

**How can I properly add UIButton so that it won't cause table scrolling issue?** Thanks in advance.

**Solution:**
Following an answer by shortstuffsushi, use findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock instead of findObjects for the UIButton.

```
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *userArray, NSError *error) {
    if(!error){
        PFUser *user = [userArray objectAtIndex:0];
        if ([[[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"followings"]containsObject:user.objectId]) {
            [followButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"following.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        } else {
            [followButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unfollow.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        [followButton setFrame:CGRectMake(280.0f, 20.0f, 20.0f, 32.0f)];
        [followButton addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapFollowButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];
```

Comment: You should really use a UITableViewCell subclass to configure anything, cellForRowAtIndexPath: is called very frequently while scrolling so you are essentially adding dozens of copies of the button to the cell with this code while scrolling...also the network call is a synchronous request as just mentioned by @shortstuffsushi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a query that makes an HTTP synchronous request within this method, that's almost certainly what's slowing it down, not the button.

`PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
[query whereKey:kPAWParseUsernameKey equalTo:[self.objects[indexPath.row] objectForKey:kPAWParseUsernameKey]];
NSArray *userArray = [query findObjects];`

As an additional note, you're adding the TouchUp listener to that cell each time this method is hit. Since cells are reused, that means the listener will be added multiple times.

Comment: So far I've only come up with this code that works in terms of function-wise but not performance. Would you please advise how to change it for the better? I'm very beginner so please bear with me.

Comment: UITableViews load and render on the main thread. The query you're making here is blocking, causing the slow you're seeing. Instead, load that data *before* loading the table. Parse provides alternate methods allow you to do this, see [their docs](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:)

Comment: In that block, you can save the result to an array property on your controller, then compare against that within your table view method (or better yet, compute that ahead of time as well).